# Group a group and count query

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, group-by

I have a query which I'm trying to group and count how many their are of the grouped column, basically what I have so far looks like:

[image: query results]

The CustomerCode is a grouped columns and it's currently being counted, but what I need it to do is group by the CustomerCode, which it does THEN group by the DomainCode as well, so it will count all the CustomerCodes which has the domainCode of say PBM113

My query so far looks like:

```
SELECT [330].DomainCode, [329].CustomerCode, Count([329].CustomerCode) AS CallCount
FROM 330 INNER JOIN 329 ON [330].DomainCode = [329].AccreditedDomainCode
WHERE ((([329].CallStatus)='N' Or ([329].CallStatus)='P' Or ([329].CallStatus)='X'))
GROUP BY [330].DomainCode, [329].CustomerCode;
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [`count(distinct)`](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2007/09/19/writing-a-count-distinct-query-in-access.aspx)

Comment: How can I go about using that in my current query?

Comment: By the way, those are some of the worst table names I've ever seen. :)

Comment: These are temporary tables, they are stored in the temp directory, they are always re-created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your current query as a subquery:

```
SELECT      DomainCode
        ,   COUNT( CustomerCode )
        ,   SUM( CallCount )
FROM       (
                SELECT      [330].DomainCode
                        ,   [329].CustomerCode
                        ,   Count([329].CustomerCode) AS CallCount
                FROM        330
                INNER JOIN  329
                        ON  [330].DomainCode = [329].AccreditedDomainCode
                WHERE       (   (   ( [329].CallStatus ) = 'N'
                                Or  ( [329].CallStatus ) = 'P'
                                Or  ( [329].CallStatus ) = 'X'
                            )   )
                GROUP BY    [330].DomainCode
                        ,   [329].CustomerCode
            ) AS CustPerDomain
GROUP BY    DomainCode;
```

Comment: Oops - hmm... this answer was based on your [tag:mysql] tag. I'm not sure if this will work in Access or not - it's SQL variant is not very standards compliant.